# What's wrong with this method of deletion in a vector?

Tags: c++

I have a deletion method that works and is as follows:

```
void deleteUserByID(int id, std::vector<Person*>& userList) 
{

    for(int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {

        if (userList.at(i)->getID() == id) {

            userList.erase(userList.begin() + i);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I was trying the following before the above and couldn't understand why it wasn't working.

Instead of using `userList.erase(userList.begin() + i);`, I was using `delete userList.at(i)`

I'm somewhat new to C++, and have been instructed to delete heap allocated memory with the "delete" keyword. I felt that should have removed it from the Vector, but was wrong.

Why doesn't the `delete userList.at(i)` work? I'm curious. Any info would be helpful.

Comment: [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) is something completely different as [`std::vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).

Comment: `delete` only calls the destructor and releases memory. It doesn’t know where a pointer to the object is being held so it can’t remove it from any containers or anything.

Comment: Off topic but related: Don't delete from the container on which you are iterating.

Comment: just use RAII, so use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>>` and problem will be solved.

Comment: @NiVeR can you explain why it is wrong to do such?

Comment: You need both `erase` and `delete`, and you will likely need `remove` as well soon. Welcome to the painful world of C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two separate concepts at play here. First, there's the maintenance of the `std::vector` that you're using. The vector's job is to hold a sequence of elements, and in many ways it doesn't really care what those elements actually are. From the vector's perspective, its elements will stick around until something explicitly comes along and says to get rid of them. The call to `erase` tells the vector "Hey, you know that element you've got at that one position? Please get rid of it." So when you make the call to `erase`, you're telling the vector to get rid of one of its elements.

Independently, there's the objects that are being stored in the vector. You're storing `Person *`s, which are pointers to `Person` objects. Those objects (I'm assuming) were allocated with `new`, so each Person essentially thinks "I'm going to live forever, or at least until someone comes around and calls `delete` on me." If you `delete` one of the Person objects, that object ceases to exist. However, the Person objects have absolutely no idea that there's a vector somewhere with pointers to people.

In order to get everything to work the way you want it to, you actually need to use a combination of both `erase` and `delete` (with a caveat that I'll mention later). If you just `erase` the pointers from the vector, then from the vector's perspective everything is cleaned up (it no longer holds pointers to the Person object in question), but from the Person's perspective the Person object is still very much alive and well because you never said to `delete` it. If you just `delete` the pointers, then from the Person's perspective everything is cleaned up (you've told the Person that it's time to go to the giant playground in the sky), but from the vector's perspective nothing was added or removed, so you now have a dangling pointer in your vector. In other words, the first option results in a memory leak - there's a Person object that was never told to clean itsefl up - and the second option results in dangling pointer - there's a pointer to what used to be a person, but which is now a bunch of bits that can be recycled however the program wishes.

Using the setup you have right now, the "best" way to handle this would be to use a combined approach. When you find an item to remove, first `delete` the pointer, *then* call `erase`. That ensures that the Person gets cleaned up and that the vector no longer has a dangling pointer in it.

But as some of the commenters have noted, there's a much better way to do this. Rather than storing `Person *`s and using raw pointers to reference the `Person` objects, use the `std::shared_ptr` type and manage your `Person` objects through `std::shared_ptr<Person>`. Unlike a regular pointer, which just says "yeah, there's a thing over there" and won't do any memory management on its own, the `std::shared_ptr` type actually owns the resource that it points at. If you `erase` a `std::shared_ptr` from a vector, the `std::shared_ptr` then says "okay, I just got kicked out of the vector, and if I'm the last pointer to the `Person`, I'll go and `delete` it for you." That means that you don't need to do any of your own memory management to clean things up.

In summary:

- Just calling `erase` gets rid of an element from the vector, but leaves a Person adrift in the heap, wondering why no one loves it anymore.
- Just calling `delete` sets the Person object free, but leaves a ghostly pointer to it in the vector that's a major hazard.
- Calling both `delete` and `erase` in the proper order will solve this problem, but isn't the ideal solution.
- Using `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers is probably the best option, since it ensures that all the right `delete`s happen automatically.

Hope this helps!

---

And a quick addendum - are you sure that you code correctly visits all the elements of the vector? For example, if you `erase` the item at index 0, all the other elements of the vector will shift back one position. But then your implementation increments `i` to 1, at which point you've skipped over the item that just got shifted back to the first position.

I'll let you think about how to resolve this. Another answer has offered a good suggestion of using `remove_if`, which is one good solution, though if for your own edification you want to roll your own version, you might want to think over how you'd address the above issue.

Comment: Your answer is extremely helpful, thank you so much!

Comment: @templatetypedef I have a quick question. Since the smart pointer/unique pointer deletes itself when it goes out of scope, how can I use that effectively in a createPerson() method? I call createPerson(), which is where the smart pointer gets created. But once that function ends, isn't that where the pointer gets deleted? How can I add the smart pointer to my vector without it getting deleted?

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those places a picture is almost certainly worth at least a thousand words. The vector is storing pointers, which point to (presumably) dynamically allocated objects, something like this:

[image]

So, the green boxes represent the elements in the vector itself. The blue boxes represent your data objects. I've separated the third one to signify the fact that it's the one we're going to (eventually) remove.

As it stands right now, your code is deleting some of the green boxes. It leaves the blue box (your data) in memory, but you no longer have a pointer to it:

[image]

At this point, you're right that the data no longer appears in the vector, so your routine has "worked" to that extent. The problem is that you no longer have access to that data, so you've leaked its memory.

What's (apparently) being suggested is that when you find the object you want to remove from the list, you should first use `delete` to destroy the data (the blue box):

[image]

...**then** use erase to remove that element from the vector:

[image]

#### Alternatives

I would *not* use a `std::shared_ptr` for a case like this. A `shared_ptr` is intended to manage objects that have shared ownership, and nothing you've said indicates that you're dealing with shared ownership. If you must use dynamically allocated objects, and don't want to manage things manually (which I agree is a good thing to avoid), you might consider using `std::unique_ptr`, or you might want to consider using a Boost [ptr_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html) instead.

Alternatively, consider changing it to a `std::vector<Person>` (i.e., store the objects directly in the vector instead of storing pointers to dynamically allocated objects). At least in my experience, this is really the right answer the vast majority of the time. If you really need to ensure against moving the `Person` objects around when the vector resizes, consider using an `std::deque<Person>` instead. A `std::deque<Person>` is fairly close to what you've created, but with at least some potential for the compiler to optimize allocation by putting a number of data objects (`Person`s, in your case) into a single block of memory, instead of allocating each one individually.

#### Conclusion

Until or unless evidence to the contrary is found, the right answer is most likely `std::vector<Person>` with `std::deque<Person>` in second place. Direct dynamic allocation of the `Person` objects, with something to automate their deletion runs a distant third place (at best).

Comment: Another very helpful response. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The other answers given summarize what you really should do in terms of design, and that is to use smart pointers.

However, if you really did use raw pointers, and allocated those entries with `new`, the way you can delete *and* erase without writing any loops is to

1. Partition the elements to `delete`
2. `delete` the elements
3. Erase the partitioned elements from the vector using `vector<T>::erase`.

Here is an example:

```
void deleteUserByID(int id, std::vector<Person*>& userList) 
{
   // partition the about-to-be deleted elements to the right of the partition
   // and all good items to the left of the partition
   auto iter = std::partition(userList.begin(), userList.end(), [&](Person *p)
                                     { return p->getID() != id; });

   // issue a delete on those elements on right of partition
   std::for_each(iter, userList.end(), [](Person *p) { delete p; });

   // now erase those elements from the vector.
   userList.erase(iter, userList.end());
}
```

The [std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) simply places all elements you wish to delete on the right of the partition (which is returned by `iter`).  Then it's just a matter of calling `delete` on those elements on the right of the partition, and finally erase those elements.

The reason why this 3-step process was done instead of directly using the `std::remove_if`  is that `std::remove_if` gives you undetermined elements in the range denoting the items that were "removed", thus issuing subsequent `delete` calls on those elements would have resulted in undefined behavior.

For example, this code, even though it looks like it would work, actually results in undefined behavior:

```
void deleteUserByID(int id, std::vector<Person*>& userList) 
{
   // move items to be removed to the end of the vector
   auto iter = std::remove_if(userList.begin(), userList.end(), [&](Person *p)
                                 { return p->getID() == id; });

   // issue a delete on those elements (this actually invokes undefined behavior)
   std::for_each(iter, userList.end(), [](Person *p) { delete p; });

   // now erase those elements from the vector (if your program even gets this far)
   userList.erase(iter, userList.end());
}
```

Basically, you can't do anything "special" to the items in the removed range (for example, call `delete`), as those items are indeterminate garbage.  The only thing you can safely do is to `erase` them.

So the trick is to partition the elements (which doesn't invalidate those items), `delete` the partitioned elements, and *then* remove them using `erase`.

*Note that if you want to keep the order of the elements that will not be deleted, then use [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) instead of `std::partition`.

Comment: I would negate condition of `partition` to place elements to remove at the end. that would avoid extra moves/copies with `erase`.

Comment: Yes, I was about to make the change to put the deleted items at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Proper way to do it is to use smart pointers and an algorithm from STL.

```
void deleteUserByID(int id, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Person>>& userList)
{
    auto endIt = std::remove_if(userList.begin(), userList.end(),
        [id](const auto &person) {
            return person->getID() == id;
        });
    userList.erase(endIt, userList.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are two different and complementary things.  For your vector

```
userList.erase(userList.begin() + i);
```

will remove the ith pointer from your vector, but will not affect the pointed at Person object in any way

```
delete userList.at(i);
```

will delete (free) the Person object pointed at by the ith pointer in your vector, but will not affect the vector in any way.

Depending on where these Person objects are coming from and what you are trying to do, you might need to do both.

Comment: So if I only called 'delete', the address of the now nonexistent object would still exist in memory? And that address would just be pointing to garbage now?

Comment: @user10150308: yes, it would still exist in the vector and might (likely would) be pointing at garbage.  Dereferencing it at that point would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Thank you!