# trying to delete spesific Object from vector and fail

Tags: c++, vector

i have a vector that contains object and i want to delete some spesific object and my program just crash with the message "Process finished with exit code 0" in my "delete (*iter)" line  , and i dont have any idea why

```
void killHero(Hero* hero,vector<Hero*>& players)
{
    std::vector<Hero*> ::iterator iter;
    int count = 0;
    for(iter=players.begin(); iter!=players.end();++iter) {
        Hero *h = *iter;
        if (h->getName() == hero->getName()) {
            delete *iter;
            players.erase(iter);
            vecorSize--;
        }
    }

}
```

my vector contains:

```
  void createNewGame(vector<Hero*> &players,int warriors, int thieves, int necromancers)
{
    string nameOfwarrior="";
    for(int i=0; i<warriors; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please insert warrior number "<< i+1 << " name:"<<endl;
        std::getline(cin,nameOfwarrior);
        try
        {
            digitCheck(nameOfwarrior);
            Warrior *warr = new Warrior(nameOfwarrior);
            players.push_back(warr);
        }
        catch(GameException& e )
        {
            e.error();
            i--;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<thieves; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please insert thief number "<< i+1 << " name:"<<endl;
        std::getline(cin,nameOfwarrior);
        try
        {
            digitCheck(nameOfwarrior);
            Thief* thief = new Thief(nameOfwarrior);
            players.push_back(thief);
        }
        catch(GameException& e)
        {
            e.error();
            i--;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<necromancers; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please insert necromancer number "<< i+1 << " name:"<<endl;
        std::getline(cin,nameOfwarrior);
        try
        {
            digitCheck(nameOfwarrior);
            Necromancer* necro = new Necromancer(nameOfwarrior);
            players.push_back(necro);
        }
        catch(GameException& e)
        {
            e.error();
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

what can solve the problem?
thank you

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Are `Hero` instances, in the `std::vector`, allocated with `new`?

Comment: yes , i did new when i input my hero to vector

Comment: @DavidZaltsman In that case, please provide [mcve].

Comment: vector iterators are invalidated when something is erased from them.

Comment: Is there more than one hero with the same name? Also, try to use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @DavidZaltsman Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583374/whats-wrong-with-this-method-of-deletion-in-a-vector/51583614#51583614).  This avoids having to write loops, and also allows you to delete and erase safely.

Answer (score 3):

`players.erase(iter)` operation invalidates `iter`. After the iteration, `++iter` is performed, and in next iteration `*iter` both of which have undefined behaviour because the iterator is invalid.

You must use following algorithm:

- If iterator is erased, then `erase` returns the iterator to next element.
- Else, increment the iterator.

Comment: Upvoted.  In addition, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583374/whats-wrong-with-this-method-of-deletion-in-a-vector/51583614#51583614) avoids writing any loops.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie would it not be sufficient to use remove_if - erase, while deleting in the predicate?

Comment: @eerorika Possibly, but I'm too chicken to try it.  Safer just to do this in stages.

Comment: Though, one should not have owning bare pointers in the first place, so there is little point arguing about how to best deal with them.